# How to prevent Android Studio from generating signed APK success if I were using wrong API level

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Currently, I have a project with min SDK API level 10.

In my code, I had accidentally use function which requires API level 19.

Previously, if I were using Eclipse, it will prevent me from building APK successfully.

However, after switching to Android Studio 1.0, it doesn't prevent me from generating signed APK? Note, I didn't use `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` for that paritcular function.

Is there any way I can enforce Android Studio 1.0, to prevent such mistake?

As you can see in my Android Studio screenshot, although I had enforced "Calling new methods on older version as error", it doesn't prevent my from building APK.

[image]

My `build.gradle` looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.myproject.gui"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    ...
```

Note, I can see an actual lint warning in my editor

[image]

I even try to add the following line in my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.myproject.gui"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    ...

    // This is important to prevent programmer mistake?!
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
    }
```

But, that doesn't prevent me from `Generate Signed APK...` successfully.

Comment: Where did you set your MinSDK ? If I remember right, the settings in your build.gradle file override what's written in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Snow I had updated my question.

Comment: I think you don't have any errors because you set your compileSdkVersion to 19, so gradle doesn't find it odd that you use a code from the SDK 19. Try put it to 10 to see if something changes ?

Comment: It's not an error to use an API call that's unavailable in the minSDK; if Eclipse was preventing you from compiling, then there's something else that's going on. It's not uncommon to allow an APK to run on an older version and to have version checks that prevent the method call in question from executing if it's not available. You have to be a little careful and use reflection to access it so it can get past the classloader, but it can be done.

Comment: To avoid myself from making such costly mistake, is to run Analyze -> Inspect Code... to avoid myself calling those API greater than minSdkVersion.